# Getting error "Login Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, passport.js, mern

I am trying to register a user using nestjs . when I tried to register my user I have an error like this. I spend hours to find out what went wrong, but I ca;t found a thing.I really need your help with this one.

[image]

[image]

This is my error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on our Discord, you forgot to add the `@Injectable()` decorator to your `AuthenticaitonService` class, which made the DI service not understand that something was supposed to be injected and thus caused the error